# Contacting DNS server via command line interface

Tags: domain-name-system, telnet, netcat

So, we are on the DNS chapter in our class, and I was wondering if there's any way possible though which I can connect to a DNS server on port 53 via command line interface (i.e Telnet or netcat) like we do for SMTP or HTTP or POP on their specific ports; I tried:

```
> telnet 8.8.8.8 53
```

But the connection was closed as soon as it was established; which I later realized was because telnet uses TCP while DNS uses UDP.

Then I tried doing the same with netcat:

```
> nc -u 8.8.8.8 53
```

Nada!
I just want to see the working of DNS with some transparency.(like with http, SMTP etc.)

Comment: I don't know what using telnet would teach you about DNS, but you can certainly **query** a DNS server from the command line. In Windows you'd use `nslookup` (with debug to see detailed information). In Linux I believe you'd use `dig`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As you note, [DNS primarily uses UDP but service is actually also provided over TCP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-4.2) (typically used for large responses and zone transfers).
This is why you managed to establish a connection in the first place when you tried `telnet`.
Your connection was closed because you weren't interacting with the service in the expected way, not because `telnet` uses TCP.

The important difference is that, unlike HTTP and SMTP which are plain text protocols and easy enough to work with directly, [DNS is a binary protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-4).

This means that you will need some DNS client program to interact with nameservers in any reasonable fashion.

[`dig`](https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/) has been the de facto standard for DNS troubleshooting for a very long time as it is very good in terms of both constructing queries and in terms of pretty-printing all the information in the response in a concise way.
(Part of BIND code-base and included in the Windows build from ISC.)

[`drill`](http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/ldns/) is another alternative with similar capabilities and essentially the same output formatting as `dig`.

`nslookup` is well known as it has been around since the dawn of time. It has been largely abandoned except on Windows and has some undesirable quirks and limited capabilities in comparison to the previously mentioned alternatives. The debug option (`set debug`) makes it usable for troubleshooting in a pinch as it greatly improves the completeness of the output, although the formatting of the debug output leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: Thank-you for your answer sir, but if I may ask, can you provide some additional info or link on **`but the service is actually also provided over TCP`**

Comment: @Jarwin Sure, link added.

Comment: can you also place a link or more information about the binary format used in UDP (/TCP) ?

Comment: @nl-x Link added

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `dig` utility, like this:

`dig @your.dns.server www.foo.bar`

Example:

`dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com`

If you want to see the step-by-step name resolution, you can do this:

`dig +add +trace @8.8.8.8 www.google.com`

Best regards!

Comment: is there a windows version of this? i dont have to do this for any work just curious :)

Comment: Yes! https://samsclass.info/40/proj/digwin.htm and http://unroutable.blogspot.com.br/2009/02/how-to-install-dig-for-windows.html :)

Comment: Seems more straightforward to go directly to the source: https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/

Comment: Using `@1.2.3.4` together with `+trace` can lead to confusing results, because the explicit nameserver specified by `@1.2.3.4` can have already updated its cache, while the recursed root nameservers can have a deprecated state.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows you can use NSlookup

```
   nslookup [-opt ...]             # interactive mode using default server
   nslookup [-opt ...] - server    # interactive mode using 'server'
   nslookup [-opt ...] host        # just look up 'host' using default server
   nslookup [-opt ...] host server # just look up 'host' using 'server'
```